# Seforim on Hilchos Niddah

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, niddah

I'm starting to learn Hilchos Niddah be'iyun (in depth).

[1] I understand that I need to learn the basics: Tur, Bais Yosef, Shulchan Aruch, Shach, Taz, Pischei Teshuva, and R Akiva Eiger. I wanted to know if anybody has any recommendation on which mefarshim on or off the page and seforim to use.

[2] And does anybody have any good shiurim to listen to? I don't want the shiurim that they have as a refresher course that are given during Shovivim.

Comment: I doubt this is the type of work you are looking for, but I mention it for the benefit of others: טהרת משה by R. Sefanyah 'Arusi. It analyzes the topic through a Maimonidean/Yemenite lens and also makes frequent reference and comparison to the practices/customs of other communities.

Answer (score 3):

1] There are many excellent mefarshim and seforim on Hilchos Niddah. In terms of those that are most popular, the Chavos Da'as and Sidrei Taharah are very well-known commentaries on Shulchan Aruch, although even those learning be'iyun would probably not be able to learn all of them in order. Many would also say that Aruch Hashulchan is pretty much a "must read".

As for more recent sefarim, there are many, many good ones. On my shelf (not that I've learned through all of them), you can find Badei Hashulchan (which is on Shulchan Aruch), Rabbi Eider's and Rabbi Soblofsky's English books (both of which are impeccably sourced and provide lomdus as well as practical rulings), and quite a few others. If you are interested in Sefardi Psak (and possibly even if you aren't), Rav Ovadia's Taharas Habayis is a must-have.

2] I would recommend looking for shiurim from Semicha programs. You can find quite a few sets on YUTorah, and I also know that Rabbi Weiner's shiurim (linked [here](http://nermichoel.org/index/shiur/media/both/category/halacha/subcategory/hilchos-niddah/speaker/rabbi-weiner)) are excellent.

Note: I would also recommend that you speak to your Rav (or sign up for some sort of Semicha program, and speak to a Rav there) who will probably be able to guide you in these matters far better than I can, especially if you are interested in actually paskening these shailos and/or doing shimush in mar'os.

Comment: See also http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=23078

Comment: I would add that I was in R' Baruch Simon's niddah shiur (all recordings available on YUTorah) and that his shiurim are excellent, as well as the chazarah shiurim of his Talmid, Rabbi Moshe Tuchman (also available on YUTorah). He also has mareh mekomos packets that you would want to print out and follow along as you listen. Available here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/850181/rabbi-baruch-simon/niddah-packets/&ved=2ahUKEwjD7-OWiMz2AhXSk4kEHdFICuMQFnoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2x9LP2cd8rI85bBiBzfWxI

Comment: @Yehuda Thanks! Rabbi Simon was one of those who I had in mind when I suggested the Semicha programs; his packets are very well-known.

Comment: Whoa. R' Shimon Eider z"l's sefer is very good - but it is absolutely incomplete. He never finished it, and the beginning reader would have no way of knowing it. He never covered וסתות, for example, and a number of other topics. It should be published with a warning, and I wrote to Feldheim and told them so.

Comment: @MichoelR I would say that the warning is required only if one thinks they are getting a full coverage of all details of hilchos niddah (e.g., for a beginner or refresher). However, for someone learning be'iyun, I think that they would find this very practical. (Also, I just looked and a) they mention in the introduction how to properly study this sefer alongside the relevant sections of Shulchan Aruch, and b) there is a very short section on vestos at the end of Volume 2.)

Comment: Well, I was a beginner when I first looked at it, and I sure didn't know any better. Needs a warning.

Answer (score 2):

The sefer Mareh Kohen by R' Rubin from Har Nof is very good. (מראה כהן / רבי יצחק מרדכי הכהן) It's short enough to get through the whole thing but it covers many topics and has mekorot (sources) that you can look up. I am not sure where you are located but I haven't been in a shul (beit knesset) here in Eretz Yisroel where there are serious learners that doesn't have it. That seems to say something about it. Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. See [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!